# Installing apps programs etc

Tags: software-installation, password, root, authentication

Im new to Ubuntu. I'm trying to install apps etc, but it keeps asking for authentication. I don't where or how to create a password. I've had a look in system settings but no joy

Answer (score 1):

When you installed Ubuntu you had to put in a username and password. This would be the password you'll need to use to install your software.

Does this ring any bells?

[image: Installation]

If you still can't remember, you will need to reset your password. This will be of use in that case: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 0):

When you made your user account you had to put in a password. Use that password when it asks for authentication.